# How to run externally

Tags: python, graphing

I have plotted a graph from a CSV file using SPYDER from PYTHON

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('GM_NB_Replica_Test.csv', skiprows=8)

data = df.ix[:,19:116].T

data.columns=df['SN']
data.plot()
plt.show()`
```

Here is my Output inside the python console:

[image: Output]

How do i get this to run externally (Not inside python console, and not in new python console)

I have already tried changing the run settings (See photo below)

[image: Run Settings]

However it just gives me a black Python CMD and then no graph.

any thoughts?

current error when running in CMD

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

From your command prompt (CMD):

```
cd C://location_of_your_script
python script.py
```

Comment: `C:///Users/eric.bell/Desktop/real replica test 2.py`
`python script.py`
Like this?

Comment: I assume that you have a python script named test_2.py
1)copy paste your script to desktop
2)open command window
3)write cd desktop
4)then write python test_2.py to command window

Comment: I'm getting an error that says: `no such file or directory`

Comment: Your files not on desktop or your file has a different name be aware of character "_"

Comment: because you named it as "real replica test 2.py" but you call it as "real_replica_test_2.py". Always prefer _ instead of space